# How to design android layout for this snapshot?

Tags: android

I am a new in android programming, I made a layout with this figure:

[image]

Now I want to know when one of these buttons clicked I should run an new activity or change visibility to false and show new layout without run a new activity, what is the best solution?
You consider that count of these buttons are more than ten.

I want show a text with image,..(when clicked) because that is a educational book and these buttons are chapters list of that book

Comment: It depends on what should happen when you click these buttons... Could you add some info?

Comment: I want show a text with image,.. because that is a educational book and these buttons are chapters list of that book

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for an example if you want to change only the layout then you could do something like this

```
  FirstButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) { 
                    FirstView();                    
            }
        });
```

/

```
   void FirstView(){
    setContentView(R.layout.yourOtherLayout); 
// then declare the layout views here. 
firstView=false;

    }
```

you can do this in all the buttons just create different methods for each

to handle the `Back Button` you can declare Boolean variables and use If else Statement to loop through them for example

```
    boolean firstView = true, secondView = true; 
@Override 

public void onBackPressed(){
        if (firstView == false ){ 
          then firstView Is Showing. 
             // show the view you want and set 
           firstView = true;
    }else if (SO ON)... 
else { super.OnBackPressed(); // exit }
}
```

Comment: thanks k0sh, but when clicked in back button how to handle that back to list of chapters

Comment: @HamidBahmanabady i re-edited my answer for complete description about how to handle the views and so on.